# notepad++ deleted files popup

Tags: popup, notepad++, delete-file

When I delete file notepad++ displays the below message:

> The file "D:\xxx.txt" does not exist any more . keep file in the editor?

Can I stop this message and silently remove deleted files from the editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message box with the question is displayed unconditionally. There cannot be anything done about removing it simply by chaging configuration.

If you have necessary programming and app building skills and you wish to remove it, search for `Notepad_plus::doCloseOrNot` in Notepad++ source file `<source root>\PowerEditor\src\Notepad_plus.cpp` and modify the code accordingly – for example to always return **No** (=do not keep file in editor) without showing a dialog. Then build Notepad++ from these modified sources so the change will be there.

Comment: where i can find Notepad++ source file.did you mean .exe file?

Comment: @user2792748 - N++ source is available for download at N++ home page. Did you experience any problems finding it?

Comment: I don't have problems . after I get the .exe file what I can do next . Can you explain more? Where I can search for search for Notepad_plus::doCloseOrNot

Comment: @user2792748 - I'm sorry if there was a misunderstanding, I meant Notepad++ source code in C++ language. From [download page](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.5.5.html) download item **Notepad++ source code**. After that, continue with Notepad++ modification, you can focus on file mentioned in the answer. Off hand I suggest commenting out lines 1689-1691 and replacing 1692 for `return IDNO;`. Then [build](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/?title=Compiling_Notepad%2B%2B) your modified EXE file from these sources. (Details are out of scope of this question.)

Comment: I have modified the answer to make more clear for reader that ceratin technical skills are required to change N++ behavior. For readers unable to perform the modification, the answer is "change in this N++ behavior cannot be achieved".

Comment: it is clear now. but another thing did you mean to comment line 1689,1690,1691 or line 1689,1691

Comment: I meant all three. You do not need them any more if you do not read result they produced, but you return simply IDNO constant at fourth line.

Comment: if the answer was helpful, do not forget to accept it so the others can find the solution more straightforward way. If you find few minutes, also please review your older questions without accepted answers whether some answers are worthy accepting. It is a fair way to reward the effort. (Of course only in case if post answers the question.)  List of your questions is available in Questions section of your user profile.